# jquery: compare radio button value with hidden value

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following likert scale implemented in html (note the hidden field at the end):

```
<ul class="likert">
    <li class="likert">Not Empathetic<input type="radio" value="1" />
    <li class="likert"><input type="radio" value="2" />
    <li class="likert"><input type="radio" value="3" />
    <li class="likert"><input type="radio" value="4" />
    <li class="likert">Very Empathetic<input type="radio" value="5" />
</ul>
<input class="answer-key" type="hidden" value="5"/>
```

I am trying to compare the value of the selected radio button with the value stored in the hidden field.

In jquery, I have the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//click handler
$('input[type=radio]').click(function(){

    var value = $(this).val();

    //DOESN'T WORK
    var answer = $(this).parent().siblings('.answer-key').val());

    compute_score(answer,value);

    });

});
```

How might I access the value of the hidden input? There will be multiple hidden answers on this page, so I need to get the value of the hidden answer for this particular likert scale. I am open to moving the hidden answer to another location (perhaps within the `<ul>`?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.parent` is not enough (that only selects the `<li>`).  I think you want `.closest('ul').siblings`...

Comment: This worked great. The .closest() function was very useful. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting the right element here. You are check for `siblings('.answer-key')` of the `li` element, not the `ul`.

```
$('input[type=radio]').click(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();

    // $(this)                                  equals <input[type=radio]>
    // $(this).parent()                         equals <li class="likert">
    // $(this).parent().siblings('.answer-key') equals nothing!
    var answer = $(this).parent().siblings('.answer-key').val();
    compute_score(answer,value);
});
```

You need `$(this).parent().parent()`, to get the `ul`. Then you can check for siblings. So this should do it:

```
 var answer = $(this).parent().parent().siblings('.answer-key').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var answer = $(this).closest('ul').next('.answer-key').val();
```

You need to get to the **ul** First ..
Then use `.next` to get the next sibling

Answer (score 0):

Here parent will select the li element

```
$(this).parent().siblings('.answer-key').val());
```

Change it as closest("ul").siblings to get the hidden element corresponding to ul.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<ul class="likert">
    <li class="likert">Not Empathetic <input name='radio_check' type="radio" value="1" />
    <li class="likert"><input type="radio" name='radio_check' value="2" />
    <li class="likert"><input type="radio" name='radio_check' value="3" />
    <li class="likert"><input type="radio" name='radio_check' value="4" />
    <li class="likert">Very Empathetic <input name='radio_check' type="radio" value="5" />
</ul>
<input class="answer-key" type="hidden" value="5"/>
```

Javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

//click handler
$('input[type=radio]').on('click',function(event){

    var value = $(this).val();

//call your javascript function
    compute_score(answer, $('input[type="hidden"].answer-key').val() );
event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

//just in case that you want to use the name as part of the selector and to verify if it's checked with is:checked for example... I added a name to the radio options.. as you can only select one, they can have the same name